# Even after mounting the windows partition Banshee fails to import files

Tags: dual-boot, mount, banshee

I have successfully mounted a windows NTFS partition by modifying fstab. While trying to import files to media library in Banshee,the file names are shown disabled and clicking on import ubuntu 16.04 freezes.System is dual-boot with windows7.

Comment: freezing is always a bug, please report banshee bugs following this: http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/

Comment: not able to open link. Takes too much time.

Comment: it works for me, almost instantly